# How can I truncate my strings with a "..." if they are too long?

Tags: c#, string

Hope somebody has a good idea. I have strings like this:

```
abcdefg
abcde
abc
```

What I need is for them to be trucated to show like this if more than a specified lenght:

```
abc ..
abc ..
abc
```

Is there any simple C# code I can use for this?

Comment: Where are you looking to do this? - in a Forms or WPF app or a website - please provide more details!

Comment: The problem with most solution is that they use a number of `Char`s as limit. Unfortunately the graphical width can vary greatly. And then there are UTF-16 surrogates, combining characters,...

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the suggested question.  This is a very general question while the suggested duplicate is an extremely specific question.

Comment: This is absolutely not a duplicate of the suggested question.

Comment: This question is not even close to the suggested duplicate please, remove the duplicate attribute. Thx.

Comment: Length in pixels/centimeters or length in characters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724840/how-can-i-truncate-my-strings-with-a-if-they-are-too-long

Comment: Depends on the context of the string `myTextBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;` in WPF for instance (XAML)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Here is the logic wrapped up in an extension method:

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxChars)
{
    return value.Length <= maxChars ? value : value.Substring(0, maxChars) + "...";
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = "abcdefg";

Console.WriteLine(s.Truncate(3));
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Your answer looks good. Please excuse my simple question but how do I use an extension method?

Comment: @Melony: Edited to include usage.

Comment: … (ellipsis) is the correct symbol for those who care. Unicode U+2026.

Comment: quick addition to include a null check

Comment: thanks @Malako `: value.Substring(0, maxChars) + (char)0x2026;`

Comment: You can also write `value.Substring(0, maxChars) + "\u2026"` The string `"\u2026"` represents the horizontal ellipsis unicode character U+2026 in C# source code.

Comment: In some cases the last character of the substring will be `space` so its important to use the `TrimEnd()` function to remove trailing `space` from the substring: `value.Substring(0, maxChars).TrimEnd()`

Answer (score 12):

All very good answers, but to clean it up just a little, if your strings are sentences, don't break your string in the middle of a word.

```
private string TruncateForDisplay(this string value, int length)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;
  var returnValue = value;
  if (value.Length > length)
  {
    var tmp = value.Substring(0, length) ;
    if (tmp.LastIndexOf(' ') > 0)
       returnValue = tmp.Substring(0, tmp.LastIndexOf(' ') ) + " ...";
  }                
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that does not break up words. Therefore the only correct one IMO.

Comment: @mxmissile - given the OP data, for "abcdefg", truncate at 3 characters, goes to "abc ...", even if this worked, it would not be correct at all.  The OP sample data clearly indicates a hard truncate in the middle of contiguous text.  Worse, as it is, this answer would generate an error.  Since the data does not contain a space, the `LastIndexOf` would return -1, and the `Substring` would cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 9):

```
public string TruncString(string myStr, int THRESHOLD)
{
    if (myStr.Length > THRESHOLD)
        return myStr.Substring(0, THRESHOLD) + "...";
    return myStr;
}
```

Ignore the naming convention it's just in case he actually needs the THRESHOLD variable or if it's always the same size.

Alternatively

```
string res = (myStr.Length > THRESHOLD) ? myStr.Substring(0, THRESHOLD) + ".." : myStr;
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this into something with one line that I could use inline?

Comment: This can produce invalid strings if it splits a codepoint in the middle :(

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version that accounts for the length of the ellipses:

```
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxChars)
    {
        const string ellipses = "...";
        return value.Length <= maxChars ? value : value.Substring(0, maxChars - ellipses.Length) + ellipses;
    }
```

Comment: if you use the ellipsis character, then there is no need for that. It's character length will always be 1 `const char ellipse = (char)0x2026;`

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built in method in the .NET Framework which does this, however this is a very easy method to write yourself. Here are the steps, try making it yourself and let us know what you come up with.

1. Create a method, perhaps an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) `public static void TruncateWithEllipsis(this string value, int maxLength)`
2. Check to see if the passed in value is greater than the `maxLength` specified using the [`Length` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx). If the `value` not greater than `maxLength`, just return the `value`.
3. If we didn't return the passed in value as is, then we know we need to truncate. So we need to get a smaller section of the string using the [`SubString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx). That method will return a smaller section of a string based on a specified start and end value. The end position is what was passed in by the `maxLength` parameter, so use that.
4. Return the sub section of the string plus the ellipsis.

A great exercise for later would be to update the method and have it break only after full words. You can also create an overload to specify how you would like to show a string has been truncated. For example, the method could return " (click for more)" instead of "..." if your application is set up to show more detail by clicking.

Answer (score 3):

Refactor with new C# features just for disclosure:

- [Nullables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) (C# 7)
- [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) (C# 6 and 7)
- [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) on strings (C# 8)

```cs
// public static class StringExtensions { ...

private static string? Truncate(this string? value, int maxChars)
    =>
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value :
    value.Length <= maxChars ? value :
    value[..maxChars] + "...";
```

Checked as "Community wiki", be free to improve answer.

Answer (score 2):

Code behind:

```
string shorten(sting s)
{
    //string s = abcdefg;
    int tooLongInt = 3;

    if (s.Length > tooLongInt)
        return s.Substring(0, tooLongInt) + "..";

    return s;
}
```

Markup:

```
<td><%= shorten(YOUR_STRING_HERE) %></td>
```

Comment: How could I fit this into: "<td>" + string + "<\td>" ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is better to implement a method for that purpose:

```
string shorten(sting yourStr)
{
//Suppose you have a string yourStr, toView and a constant value 

    string toView;
    const int maxView = 3;

    if (yourStr.Length > maxView)
        toView = yourStr.Substring(0, maxView) + " ..."; // all you have is to use Substring(int, int) .net method
    else
        toView = yourStr;
return toView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question after searching for "C# truncate ellipsis". Using various answers, I created my own solution with the following features:

1. An extension method
2. Add an ellipsis
3. Make the ellipsis optional
4. Validate that the string is not null or empty before attempting to truncate it.

   ```
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       public static string Truncate(this string value, 
           int maxLength, 
           bool addEllipsis = false)
       {
           // Check for valid string before attempting to truncate
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;

           // Proceed with truncating
           var result = string.Empty;
           if (value.Length > maxLength)
           {
               result = value.Substring(0, maxLength);
               if (addEllipsis) result += "...";
           }
           else
           {
               result = value;
           }

           return result;
       }
   }
   ```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "abcdefg";
if (s.length > 3)
{
    s = s.substring(0,3);
}
```

You can use the Substring function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is some sample code:

```
string str = "abcdefg";
if (str.Length > X){
   str = str.Substring(0, X) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem recently. I was storing a "status" message in a nvarcharMAX DB field which is 4000 characters. However my status messages were building up and hitting the exception.

But it wasn't a simple case of truncation as an arbitrary truncation would orphan part of a status message, so I really needed to "truncate" at a consistent part of the string.

I solved the problem by converting the string to a string array, removing the first element and then restoring to a string.  Here is the code ("CurrentStatus" is the string holding the data)...

```
        if (CurrentStatus.Length >= 3750)
        {
            // perform some truncation to free up some space.

            // Lets get the status messages into an array for processing...
            // We use the period as the delimiter, then skip the first item and re-insert into an array.

            string[] statusArray = CurrentStatus.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                    .Skip(1).ToArray();

            // Next we return the data to a string and replace any escaped returns with proper one.
            CurrentStatus = (string.Join(".", statusArray))
                                    .Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine);


        }
```

Hope it helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

This is my helper method. It almost does exactly what you want it to do, albeit it that it splits the string with two dots right in the middle.

```
public static string SplitToMaxLength(string s, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false && maxLength > 1 && s.Length > maxLength)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        //E.g. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
        //E.g. maxLength: 20
        //E.g. 9
        var splitLength = (int)(Math.Floor(maxLength / (double)2) - 1);
        //Take the left part of the string
        //E.g. abcdefghi
        sb.Append(s.Substring(0, splitLength));
        //Merge together with two dots                 
        sb.Append("..");
        //Take the right part of the string
        //E.g. rstuvwxyz
        sb.Append(s.Substring(s.Length - splitLength, splitLength));
        //E.g, result: abcdefghi..rstuvwxyz
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    return s;
}
```

DotNetFiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLN4hV